# R: dynamic arrange call based on what columns are included

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make my `arrange` call dynamic. Currently all of the possible different columns can be found in the data(SQL_Table) below:

```
# A tibble: 144,000 x 15
   plan  class gender band  marital_status acceleration extension inflation iss_age cell    dur db_perk accel_perk ext_perk
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <chr>          <chr>        <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     1   0.196     0.0035       NA
 2 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     2   0.231     0.0148       NA
 3 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     3   0.375     0.032        NA
 4 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     4   0.399     0.0528       NA
 5 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     5   0.451     0.0767       NA
 6 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     6   0.513     0.0997       NA
 7 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     7   0.595     0.121        NA
 8 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     8   0.678     0.145        NA
 9 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~     9   0.761     0.174        NA
10 Basi~   111 F      1a    Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      Basi~    10   0.844     0.207        NA
# ... with 143,990 more rows, and 1 more variable: attage <dbl>
```

Sometimes my data will not have all of the columns. For example class and band may be excluded:

```
# A tibble: 144,000 x 13
   plan   gender marital_status acceleration extension inflation iss_age cell          dur db_perk accel_perk ext_perk attage
   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>          <chr>        <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     1   0.196     0.0035       NA     41
 2 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     2   0.231     0.0148       NA     42
 3 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     3   0.375     0.032        NA     43
 4 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     4   0.399     0.0528       NA     44
 5 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     5   0.451     0.0767       NA     45
 6 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     6   0.513     0.0997       NA     46
 7 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     7   0.595     0.121        NA     47
 8 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     8   0.678     0.145        NA     48
 9 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~     9   0.761     0.174        NA     49
10 BasicF F      Married        A.24         E.0       AC3.EC3   40      BasicFF240~    10   0.844     0.207        NA     50
# ... with 143,990 more rows
```

I want an `arrange` call that will arrange my data by columns left to right ending with 'iss_age' and then 'dur' is always at the end.

For the top tibble my `arrange` call would look like this:

```
SQL_Table %>%
  arrange(plan,class, gender,band,marital_status,acceleration, extension, inflation, iss_age, dur)
```

For the 2nd tibble it would look like this: (notice class and band are exluded)

```
SQL_Table %>%
  arrange(plan,gender,marital_status, acceleration, extension, inflation,iss_age, dur)
```

The variables that may or may not be included are:
plan,class,gender,band,marital_status,acceleration,extension, and inflation.

The rest of the variables will always be included.

Is there a way to do this dynamically based on what columns are included in my data set?

Comment: If you can assume that columns are always going to be in the correct order, then I would do what @Axeman suggests. If things are more complicated I would suggest thinking about this differently: add the missing columns with NAs and then just have one simple, non-dynamic arrange() call.

Comment: @ Axeman This would work except I don't want variable db_perk, accel_perk, etc. in the arrange call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrange_at` is useful here, since it allows defining the columns using the `vars()` construct.

An example:

```
as.data.frame(Titanic) %>% 
  arrange_at(vars(everything()))
```

> ```
>    Class    Sex   Age Survived Freq
> 1    1st   Male Child       No    0
> 2    1st   Male Child      Yes    5
> 3    1st   Male Adult       No  118
> 4    1st   Male Adult      Yes   57
> 5    1st Female Child       No    0
> 6    1st Female Child      Yes    1
> 7    1st Female Adult       No    4
> 8    1st Female Adult      Yes  140
> 9    2nd   Male Child       No    0
> 10   2nd   Male Child      Yes   11
> 11   2nd   Male Adult       No  154
> 12   2nd   Male Adult      Yes   14
> 13   2nd Female Child       No    0
> 14   2nd Female Child      Yes   13
> 15   2nd Female Adult       No   13
> 16   2nd Female Adult      Yes   80
> 17   3rd   Male Child       No   35
> 18   3rd   Male Child      Yes   13
> 19   3rd   Male Adult       No  387
> 20   3rd   Male Adult      Yes   75
> 21   3rd Female Child       No   17
> 22   3rd Female Child      Yes   14
> 23   3rd Female Adult       No   89
> 24   3rd Female Adult      Yes   76
> 25  Crew   Male Child       No    0
> 26  Crew   Male Child      Yes    0
> 27  Crew   Male Adult       No  670
> 28  Crew   Male Adult      Yes  192
> 29  Crew Female Child       No    0
> 30  Crew Female Child      Yes    0
> 31  Crew Female Adult       No    3
> 32  Crew Female Adult      Yes   20
> ```

In your case, you may want to try:

```
SQL_Table %>% 
  arrange_at(vars(1:iss_age, dur))
```

But your data is hard to read in.

You could also use `one_of` to select variables that may or may not be present.